# React-Dropzone how convert each file to base64

Tags: reactjs, react-dropzone

I am using react-dropzone plugin for file uploads. I worried how i can convert each file to base64:

eg:

Here is my function where i get files: 
I am creating here for example thumb for each file and attach to object. But how add to item here prop like base64string: and it will keep base64 data for each file?

```
this.onDrop = files => {
      files.map(file =>
        Object.assign(file, {
          preview: URL.createObjectURL(file),
        })
      );
    };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check this out,you can get files and then you can store them into images array of state instance.

```
onDropHandler = (files) => {
    files.map(file => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (event) => {
            //store result into your state array.
            this.setState(prevState => {
                const updatedImages = [...prevState.images, event.target.result];
                return {
                    images: updatedImages,
                }
            })
            console.log(event.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
}
```

Comment: i'm passing the files to redux state via action it's okey but with this way i'm losing my Object.assign(file, {
          preview: URL.createObjectURL(file),
        })

Comment: @user3348410 you can do Object assign after  *files.map(file => {*
and for redux call, you can add *addFile(event.target.result)* inside  *reader.onload* callback function and update images array from reducer.

Comment: I didn't understand :/ can you edit your answer with this way ?

Comment: Just  preview: URL.createObjectURL(file), this thing not working always. anymore it's for showing thumbnail of uploaded files.

Answer (score 0):

With this code you get an array with the base64 data and blob url for the preview.

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])

const onDrop = (files) => {
files.map((file) => {
  const reader = new FileReader()
  reader.onload = (e) => {
    setdata(
      files.map((file) =>
        Object.assign(file, {
          preview: URL.createObjectURL(file),
          base64Image: e.target.result,
        })
      )
    )
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(file)
})
```

}